# How to efficiently parse large HTML div-class and span data on Python BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

**The data needed**:

I want to scrape through two webpages, one here: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/balance-sheet?p=AAPL and the other: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL.
From the first page, I need values of the row called **Total Assets**. This would be 5 values in that row named: 365,725,000 375,319,000 321,686,000 290,479,000    231,839,000 
Then I need 5 values of the row named **Total Current Liabilities**. These would be: 43,658,000 38,542,000  27,970,000  20,722,000  11,506,000
From the second link, I need 10 values of the row named **Operating Income or Loss**. These would be: 52,503,000    48,999,000  55,241,000  33,790,000  18,385,000.

**EDIT**: I need the TTM value too, and then the five years' values mentioned above. Thanks.
Here is the logic of what I want. I want to run this module, and when run, I want the output to be:

```
TTM array: 365725000, 116866000, 64423000
year1 array: 375319000, 100814000, 70898000
year2 array: 321686000, 79006000, 80610000
```

**My code**:

This is what I have written so far. I can extract the value within the div class if I just put it in a variable as shown below. However, how do I loop efficiently through the 'div' classes as there are thousands of them in the page. In other words, how do I find just the values I am looking for?

```
# Import libraries
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Set the URL you want to webscrape from
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/balance-sheet?p=AAPL'

# Connect to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse HTML and save to BeautifulSoup object¶
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
soup1 = BeautifulSoup("""<div class="D(tbc) Ta(end) Pstart(6px) Pend(4px) Bxz(bb) Py(8px) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(90px) Miw(110px)--pnclg" data-test="fin-col"><span>321,686,000</span></div>""", "html.parser")
spup2 = BeautifulSoup("""<span data-reactid="1377">""", "html.parser");

#This works
print(soup1.find("div", class_="D(tbc) Ta(end) Pstart(6px) Pend(4px) Bxz(bb) Py(8px) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(90px) Miw(110px)--pnclg").text)

#How to loop through all the relevant div classes?
```

Comment: In the AAPL page you link to, there are only 3 columns (for Sep 30 on 2018, 2017 and 2016). Are these enough?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'loop through all the relevant div classes'? Do you just want to find the HTML class for all the values you are interested in? In that case when you rightclick on the webpage and select 'inspect' (or press CTRL + SHIFT + C in Chrome) you can hover over the items on the webpage and it will show you the HTML behind it.

Comment: So you don't need the TTM column for Operating Income or Loss?

Comment: Also, can you use lxml instead of beautifulsoup? It's much simpler in this case.

Comment: Yes, I need the TTM column too! Sorry if I missed it. I made the edit now. Yes, I can use lxml if you have a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions for parse `html` use 'BeautifulSoup' which is helpful for me maybe helpful for you.

> 1. use 'id' to location the element, instead of using 'class' because the 'class' change more frequently than id.
> 2. use structure info to location the element instead of using 'class', the structure info change less frequently.
> 3. use headers with user-agent info to get response is always better than no headers. In this case, if do not specify headers info, you can not find id 'Col1-1-Financials-Proxy', but you can find 'Col1-3-Financials-Proxy', which is not same with result in Chrome inspector.

Here is runnable codes for your requirement use structure info to location elements. You definitely can use 'class' info to make it. Just remember that when your code do not work well, check the website's source code.

```py
# import libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# set the URL you want to webscrape from
first_page_url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/balance-sheet?p=AAPL'
second_page_url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36'
}

#################
# first page
#################

print('*' * 10, ' FIRST PAGE RESULT ', '*' * 10)

total_assets = {}
total_current_liabilities = {}
operating_income_or_loss = {}
page1_table_keys = []
page2_table_keys = []

# connect to the first page URL
response = requests.get(first_page_url, headers=headers)

# parse HTML and save to BeautifulSoup object¶
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
# the nearest id to get the result
sheet = soup.find(id='Col1-1-Financials-Proxy')
sheet_section_divs = sheet.section.find_all('div', recursive=False)
# last child
sheet_data_div = sheet_section_divs[-1]
div_ele_table = sheet_data_div.find('div').find('div').find_all('div', recursive=False)
# table header
div_ele_header = div_ele_table[0].find('div').find_all('div', recursive=False)
# first element is label, the remaining element containing data, so use range(1, len())
for i in range(1, len(div_ele_header)):
    page1_table_keys.append(div_ele_header[i].find('span').text)
# table body
div_ele = div_ele_table[-1]
div_eles = div_ele.find_all('div', recursive=False)
tgt_div_ele1 = div_eles[0].find_all('div', recursive=False)[-1]
tgt_div_ele1_row = tgt_div_ele1.find_all('div', recursive=False)[-1]
tgt_div_ele1_row_eles = tgt_div_ele1_row.find('div').find_all('div', recursive=False)
# first element is label, the remaining element containing data, so use range(1, len())
for i in range(1, len(tgt_div_ele1_row_eles)):
    total_assets[page1_table_keys[i - 1]] = tgt_div_ele1_row_eles[i].find('span').text
tgt_div_ele2 = div_eles[1].find_all('div', recursive=False)[-1]
tgt_div_ele2 = tgt_div_ele2.find('div').find_all('div', recursive=False)[-1]
tgt_div_ele2 = tgt_div_ele2.find('div').find_all('div', recursive=False)[-1]
tgt_div_ele2_row = tgt_div_ele2.find_all('div', recursive=False)[-1]
tgt_div_ele2_row_eles = tgt_div_ele2_row.find('div').find_all('div', recursive=False)
# first element is label, the remaining element containing data, so use range(1, len())
for i in range(1, len(tgt_div_ele2_row_eles)):
    total_current_liabilities[page1_table_keys[i - 1]] = tgt_div_ele2_row_eles[i].find('span').text

print('Total Assets', total_assets)
print('Total Current Liabilities', total_current_liabilities)

#################
# second page, same logic as the first page
#################

print('*' * 10, ' SECOND PAGE RESULT ', '*' * 10)

# Connect to the second page URL
response = requests.get(second_page_url, headers=headers)

# Parse HTML and save to BeautifulSoup object¶
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
# the nearest id to get the result
sheet = soup.find(id='Col1-1-Financials-Proxy')
sheet_section_divs = sheet.section.find_all('div', recursive=False)
# last child
sheet_data_div = sheet_section_divs[-1]
div_ele_table = sheet_data_div.find('div').find('div').find_all('div', recursive=False)
# table header
div_ele_header = div_ele_table[0].find('div').find_all('div', recursive=False)
# first element is label, the remaining element containing data, so use range(1, len())
for i in range(1, len(div_ele_header)):
    page2_table_keys.append(div_ele_header[i].find('span').text)
# table body
div_ele = div_ele_table[-1]
div_eles = div_ele.find_all('div', recursive=False)
tgt_div_ele_row = div_eles[4]
tgt_div_ele_row_eles = tgt_div_ele_row.find('div').find_all('div', recursive=False)
for i in range(1, len(tgt_div_ele_row_eles)):
    operating_income_or_loss[page2_table_keys[i - 1]] = tgt_div_ele_row_eles[i].find('span').text

print('Operating Income or Loss', operating_income_or_loss)
```

Output with header info:

```py
**********  FIRST PAGE RESULT  **********
Total Assets {'9/29/2018': '365,725,000', '9/29/2017': '375,319,000', '9/29/2016': '321,686,000'}
Total Current Liabilities {'9/29/2018': '116,866,000', '9/29/2017': '100,814,000', '9/29/2016': '79,006,000'}
**********  SECOND PAGE RESULT  **********
Operating Income or Loss {'ttm': '64,423,000', '9/29/2018': '70,898,000', '9/29/2017': '61,344,000', '9/29/2016': '60,024,000'}
```

Comment: Thanks. In the output, I see 3 values for Total Assets (TA) and Total Current Liabilities (TCA) and 4 values OI&L. Is there a way to pass a variable to detect the number of columns in that table to get and get uniform set of values. Then, how do I save these to an array - one for TA, one for TCA and one for OIL? And then check if all arrays have the same non-empty data type. (I don't understand the line for i in range(1, len(tgt_div_ele1_row_eles)))... that's why I don't know how to get more values.

Comment: You can use the table header to check the columns data number. Although I don't think array is useful for you. You should use the header as key to help you to process your logic. For the range part, because the first children element is label, so  from 1 to `len(chilrend_elements)` to get the data info. I have updated my answer, please check it again.

Comment: In your output, the total assets and total current liability values are the same. That's incorrect I think. Should be changed to 'ele2'?

Comment: Also, let's say one of the values is not available in the website.. say total assets is set to '-' in the Finance website. How do we handle just that value and skip to the next one?

Comment: Also, in many other URLs, when data is not available, I get a ''NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'' error. How to alleviate it? Thanks.

Comment: Have fixed the answer.  IMO, you don't need to skip the '-' value which is the part of your data source and mean there is no value in that date, you can handle it later. For the 'NoneType' object error, you should use `try catch` to handle it and check the html structure. If you can provide me a url which raise this error, I can update the answer to demo how to handle it.

Comment: @Zac based on the comments in all the answers, I have noted you continue to change the requirements related to your original question.  It seems that you need someone to write a complete solution to handle all the potential possibles for all the companies listed at Yahoo Finance.  You might want to consider revising your needs and increasing the bounty, because you seem to be looking for a finished solution with authentication, error handling, and other things not yet defined.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex No, I didn't ask for a complete solution. Just trying to understand the error that came with the solution and asking a further query to understand how sth works since I don't know about it. It looks like you are on all the comments trying to tell me what I should and shouldn't say.

Comment: @Zac I'm just asking you to define your requirements better.  Some of the items that you need can be fleshed out with some testing on your side, especially the try catch blocks and other tasks. I'm not trying to be harsh in my comments, but I am trying to have you understand that event comment to modify the code in the answers require effort and testing.

Comment: @Fogmoon One more quick observation. In the URL we've been using, there is a "Quarterly" tab... Upon viewing its div, it's exactly the same as the yearly ones we've been using, but the values change. How would you go about parsing that?
Just asking to learn.

Comment: @Zac You can use Chrome inspector to get the underneath network request info. Open with `F12 -> Network -> XHR`,  then switch the `Quarterly` tab, see the `XHR` request, you can get the real url(/AAPL?....) which used to get the table data, also which you can directly use in your code to get the data. Inspect with the Chrome inspector, you always can get you want.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT - At the request of @Life is complex, edited to add date headings.

Try this using lxml:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/balance-sheet?p=AAPL'
url2 = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL'
page = requests.get(url)
page2 = requests.get(url2)


tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
tree2 = html.fromstring(page2.content)

total_assets = []
Total_Current_Liabilities = []
Operating_Income_or_Loss = []
heads = []


path = '//div[@class="rw-expnded"][@data-test="fin-row"][@data-reactid]'
data_path = '../../div/span/text()'
heads_path = '//div[contains(@class,"D(ib) Fw(b) Ta(end)")]/span/text()'

dats = [tree.xpath(path),tree2.xpath(path)]

for entry in dats:
    heads.append(entry[0].xpath(heads_path))
    for d in entry[0]:
        for s in d.xpath('//div[@title]'):
            if s.attrib['title'] == 'Total Assets':
                total_assets.append(s.xpath(data_path))
            if s.attrib['title'] == 'Total Current Liabilities':
                Total_Current_Liabilities.append(s.xpath(data_path))
            if s.attrib['title'] == 'Operating Income or Loss':
                Operating_Income_or_Loss.append(s.xpath(data_path))

del total_assets[0]
del Total_Current_Liabilities[0]
del Operating_Income_or_Loss[0]

print('Date   Total Assets Total_Current_Liabilities:')
for date,asset,current in zip(heads[0],total_assets[0],Total_Current_Liabilities[0]):    
         print(date, asset, current)
print('Operating Income or Loss:')
for head,income in zip(heads[1],Operating_Income_or_Loss[0]):
         print(head,income)
```

Output:

```
Date      Total Assets Total_Current_Liabilities:
9/29/2018 365,725,000 116,866,000
9/29/2017 375,319,000 100,814,000
9/29/2016 321,686,000 79,006,000
Operating Income or Loss:
ttm       64,423,000
9/29/2018 70,898,000
9/29/2017 61,344,000
9/29/2016 60,024,000
```

Of course, if so desired, this can be easily incorporated into a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200537/discussion-on-answer-by-jack-fleeting-how-to-efficiently-parse-large-html-div-cl).